# How to use elements in two files at respective position for calulation using perl?

Tags: perl

I have two text files.
1.I want to divide each element of both files by a number present in the respective files.
2. I want to calculate **Square of difference between values obtained by above calculation** at respective index position in both files.

file1:

> ```
>   1000    1.45            1450    1.56            2559     
>     335 0.35            499 0.54            1104    
>     1433    1.49            1498    1.62            2511    
>     684 0.71            263 0.28            1481
> ```
>
> 1111 **(DIVIDE EACH ELEMENT BY THIS NUMBER)

file2:

> ```
>   2000    1.45            1450    1.56            2559     
>     335 0.35            499 0.54            1104    
>     1433    1.49            1498    1.62            2511    
>     684 0.71            263 0.28            1481
> ```
>
> 2222 **(DIVIDE EACH ELEMENT BY THIS NUMBER)

I want the output e.g. for first element [(1000/1111)-(2000/2222)] ^2 and so on ...

(Note: There are equal number of white spaces or tabs in both files)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use List::MoreUtils qw<pairwise>;
print"Enter file 1: ";
chomp($file=<STDIN>);
open(FH,$file);


print"Enter file 2: ";
chomp($hspfile=<STDIN>);
open(FH1,$hspfile);


open(OUT,">$file.$hspfile.txt");

my @list1 = split '\s+', <FH>;
my @list2 = split '\s+', <FH1>;

my @diff  = pairwise { ($p - $q)^2 } @list1, @list2;


print OUT "@diff";
close FH;
close FH1;
```

**this code does not run at blank spaces.**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie;

my @data;

for my $file (qw/ file1.txt file2.txt /) {
  open my $fh, '<', $file;
  local $/;
  my $data = <$fh>;
  my $i = 0;
  push @{$data[$i++]}, $_ for  $data =~ /[0-9.]+/g;
}

my $divisor = pop @data;
for (@data) {
  my $val = $_->[0] / $divisor->[0] - $_->[1] / $divisor->[1];
  printf "%.10f\n", $val * $val;
}
```

**output**

```
0.0000000000
0.0000004258
0.4258414140
0.0000004929
1.3263326558
0.0227301083
0.0000000248
0.0504327886
0.0000000591
0.2468596095
0.4159147013
0.0000004497
0.4545017058
0.0000005315
1.2770423982
0.0947597910
0.0000001021
0.0140095243
0.0000000159
0.4442444469
```